# UPDATE with LEFT JOIN and IS NULL results in extremely low performance

Tags: mysql, sql

Today, we had major performance issue caused by this exact query (with different names of course):

```
UPDATE foo
LEFT JOIN bar 
ON bar.foo_id = foo.id
SET foo.flag = 1
WHERE bar.foo_id IS NULL;
```

The software is third-party and we didn't write the code or database schema.

`foo` has 42k rows, `bar` has 130k. A particular `foo.id` occurred very often in `bar.foo_id`. (`bar` is a relationship table implementing an m:n relationship between `foo` and `qux`. Almost each row in `qux` will have a relationship with a specific `foo` row and then to several more that are unique to it. There may be more duplicates, likely not important.) An index on `foo.id` exists. `bar.foo_id` is part of an index also containing `bar.qux_id` and unrelated `bar.text`.

The query ran for 55min at 100% CPU of a `db.t3.medium` instance using Aurora MySQL 5.7. The slowlog stated `Rows_examined: 5719954827`.

Can someone explain what exactly the reason for this number and the resulting low performance is? 42k * 130k is close to it so that probably has something to do with it.

In our case, we could simply `GROUP BY foo_id` and then join with the result instead of `bar` which solved the problem. However, that won't be possible in all circumstances - and I don't think creating an index on `bar.foo_id` should have an effect as `NULL` values can only occur due to the `JOIN` statement.

The `EXPLAIN` output is as follows:

```
id|select_type|table            |partitions|type |possible_keys|key                  |key_len|ref|rows  |filtered|Extra                   |
--+-----------+-----------------+----------+-----+-------------+---------------------+-------+---+------+--------+------------------------+
 1|UPDATE     |foo              |          |ALL  |             |                     |       |   | 42921|   100.0|                        |
 1|SIMPLE     |bar              |          |index|             |uidx_qux_foo         |780    |   |129465|    10.0|Using where; Using index|
```

To my knowledge, `EXPLAIN PLAN` is not available in MySQL.

Comment: Your query has smell. Bar should have a pk so you should be checking bar.pk or any other not null column.

Comment: I'm specifically interested in the reason, not a solution - as I said, we didn't write the code and it's already improved without changing the schema. And bar does have a PK - I don't see how that's helpful here. The objective of the query is flagging rows in foo that are not referenced in qux so looking at these few bits of the code, they should just have used ON DELETE.

Comment: This could be written better using `not exists`

Comment: Have a look at (and post in your question) the EXPLAIN PLAN which should show what was happening

Comment: As you noticed, the very high count of examined rows is approaching the product of your two tables. This is due to the full table scan caused by the lack of index on bar.foo_id

Comment: Updating 5.7B rows?  Bad schema design.  Let's discuss why you need to do huge Updates.

Answer (score 0):

You're only writing fields in one table, the aptly-named `foo`, so write your query to only seek/scan *once* into that one table:

```
update foo set flag = 1 where ...
```

Instead, what you wrote does a product of your two (three?) tables and then sets the value for every single one of the resulting rows. That's needlessly wasteful, since, again, you only want to set data in your `foo` table at most once per row.

And once you fix your overall logic, what you're left with is the most typical database access pattern: providing correct indexes for your `select` statement (ie, the part after `where` above). A simple `explain plan` should show you exactly what the problem is, if any. Your post is of no help at all here.

Answer (score 0):

`Rows_examined: 5719954827` is a strong indicator.

Change the query to this "semi-join".  It will not need to *repeatedly* set foo.flag, but will do int only once per row in foo.

```
UPDATE foo
    SET foo.flag = 1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM bar
                         WHERE bar.foo_id = foo.id );
```

That will probably give you something like "84K rows examined" (84K = 2*42K).

And `bar` *does* need an `INDEX` *starting* with `foo_id`.

Why do you need this flag?  Why do you need to change lots of rows at once?  Can't you design the app some other way?

For any further discuss, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.